# How to create a generic string of letters and numbers for "n" clusters in R to add in a dataframe?

Tags: r, range

I have this:

```
df<-structure(list(x = c(-0.803739264931451, 0.852850728148773, 0.927179506105653, -0.752626056626365, 0.706846224294882, 1.0346985222527, -0.475845197699957, -0.460301566967151, -0.680301544955355, -1.03196929988978), y = c(-0.853052609097935, 0.367618436999606, -0.274902437566225, -0.511565170496435, 0.81067919693492, 0.394655023166806, 0.989760805249143, -0.858997792847955, -0.66149481321353, -0.0219935446644728), shape = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Output:

| x | y | shape |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -0.8037393 | -0.85305261 | 1 |
| 0.8528507 | 0.36761844 | 1 |
| 0.9271795 | -0.27490244 | 2 |
| -0.7526261 | -0.51156517 | 2 |
| 0.7068462 | 0.81067920 | 2 |
| 1.0346985 | 0.39465502 | 2 |
| -0.4758452 | 0.98976081 | 3 |
| -0.4603016 | -0.85899779 | 3 |
| -0.6803015 | -0.66149481 | 4 |
| -1.0319693 | -0.02199354 | 4 |

**Expected output:**
How to create a generic string of letters and numbers for "n" clusters in R to add in a dataframe,as shown below:

*obs: for example, if there were 100 clusters, the label of cluster 100 could be AA1 and so on.*

```
df$label<-   #What is the correct code for this problem?
```

| x | y | shape | label |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| -0.8037393 | -0.85305261 | 1 | A1 |
| 0.8528507 | 0.36761844 | 1 | A2 |
| 0.9271795 | -0.27490244 | 2 | B1 |
| -0.7526261 | -0.51156517 | 2 | B2 |
| 0.7068462 | 0.81067920 | 2 | B3 |
| 1.0346985 | 0.39465502 | 2 | B4 |
| -0.4758452 | 0.98976081 | 3 | C1 |
| -0.4603016 | -0.85899779 | 3 | C2 |
| -0.6803015 | -0.66149481 | 4 | D1 |
| -1.0319693 | -0.02199354 | 4 | D2 |

Comment: so the shape value is somehow related to the letters? ie shape 1 equals A, shape 2 equals B, etc?

Comment: @langtang, Yes. The shape value is somehow related to the letters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small function that should do it for you:

```
f <- function(g,n) {
  letter_index = if_else(g%%26 ==0, 26, g%%26)
  paste0(
    paste0(rep(LETTERS[letter_index], times = ceiling(g/26)), collapse=""),
    1:n)
}
```

Now apply that function to each shape value, using `group_by()` and `mutate()`

```
df %>% 
  group_by(shape) %>% 
  mutate(code = f(cur_group_id(), n()))
```

Output:

```
        x       y shape code 
    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl> <chr>
 1 -0.804 -0.853      1 A1   
 2  0.853  0.368      1 A2   
 3  0.927 -0.275      2 B1   
 4 -0.753 -0.512      2 B2   
 5  0.707  0.811      2 B3   
 6  1.03   0.395      2 B4   
 7 -0.476  0.990      3 C1   
 8 -0.460 -0.859      3 C2   
 9 -0.680 -0.661      4 D1   
10 -1.03  -0.0220     4 D2
```

Explanation:

- The function `f()` takes two values, an integer number indicating the group number (passed by `cur_groupid()`) and the number of values in that `shape` value (passed by `n()`). In the function, we use modulo to get the right number of times to replicate the LETTERS value, and then we paste it to the sequence from 1 to n

Comment: This doesn't seem to work beyond 26 distinct shapes, try `f(28, 3)`

Comment: Sorry @r2evans, I initially forgot the modulo... do you see the update to my solution?

Comment: it should work now.. thanks for cathing my error

Comment: Nice! Puts my overly-complicated hack to shame.

Comment: I still didn't quite get it right.. Now I think I've got it though!